# Angular 7 - http posts - no PAYLOAD sent inside headers

Tags: php, angular, post, angular7

I just created an angular 7 project

I try to send a post with some data, nothing is set in the header part

so on the server side I only get the php script called, nothing in the $_POST array

**this code works fine in angular 5**, I should see the data in the header log in chrome

```
    createPostOptions() {
        let headers = new Headers({
            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        });

        let options = new RequestOptions({ headers: headers, withCredentials: true });
        return options;
    }

    getParts(): Observable<any> 
    {
        return this.http.post('http://localhost/site/data.php',{command:'getParts'}, this.createPostOptions())
            .pipe(map((response: Response) => {
                return this.processData(response,this.router);
            }));
    }
```

php code:

```
function cors()
{
    header("HTTP/1.1 " . "200" . " " . "OK");
    header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, POST, OPTIONS");    
    header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Accept, Content-Type, Access-Control-Allow-Credentials, Access-Control-Allow-Origin, Access-Control-Allow-Headers, Access-Control-Allow-Methods, X-Requested-With, X-API-KEY, X-Auth-Token, X-Requested-With, Authorization, Content-Range, Content-Disposition, Origin, Access-Control-Request-Method');
    header('Access-Control-Max-Age: 86400');
    header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: '."http://localhost");
    header('Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true');   
}

//-----------------------------------

if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']=="OPTIONS")
{
    cors();
}
else
{
    ...
}
```

[image]
I should see something like this

[image]
Any help apreciated

Comment: where are you using `createPostOptions` ?

Comment: `'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*'` is nonsense. `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` is a **response** header, not a request header.

Comment: @Quentin this was clearly overlooked by everyone, it is not a problem about php, it's about angular not sending data through the headers and is not AFAIK a duplicate...I updated the question, please kindly look at it again

Comment: @phil123456 — Angular is not sending the data because PHP is not responding to the preflight OPTIONS request with permission for it to send the data. Duplicate added for that other problem.

Comment: I updated my question, forgot about the cors indeed, but still not working

Answer (score 0):

Since you are sending json in the body, but not as post parameters, you need something like

```
$jsonInput = file_get_contents('php://input');
$obj = json_decode($jsonInput);
$command = $obj->command;
```

Comment: that's right, completely forgot the answers where supposed to go into php://input in this case...thanks you made my day :-)

Comment: but it only solves php part, the issue is on angular side too ...no data is sent in the header

Comment: @phil123456 After your update it's a different question now... The problem was  about php.... whatheader are you expecting in an OPTIONS request exactly?

Comment: just updated again, I forgot to copy the cors code form my angular 5 project, but although I reply with the CORS eheaders, the actual POST method is not executed by chrome...stilll digging

Comment: apparently Access-Control-Request-Headers: access-control-allow-headers,access-control-allow-methods are not sent

Comment: @phil123456  Chrome usually adds the error in the console. Maybe it's because you forgot to add the port (4200) for allow-origin in your cors function

Comment: yeah just found it out, stupid of me, thanks it works now